# MFC CDateTimeCtrl show none

Tags: c++, checkbox, mfc, datetimepicker

I put a `CDateTimeCtrl` on a dialog, and defined its property of "Show None" on.
It makes the checkbox near the date, checked.

I want the dialog's default value to be this checkbox unchecked.
How can I handle this property and set its value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CDateTimeCtrl* dt = NULL;
GetDlgItem(DATE_TIME_CTRL, dt);
dt->SetTime();
```